# Cross Domain Iframe height manipulation

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

**My problem**:

I got an iframe which links to various external websites.

I do not have access to the external sites at all!

What i want to achieve is to nest my Iframe with 100% height/width of the actual website into a fixed sized div so I can apply custom scrollbars on the this div.

So far I have the following markup:

```
<div class="Content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 500px; width: 500px; overflow: auto;">
   <iframe id="mainframe" name="mainframe" src="http://www.fisk.dk" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

As expected, the Iframe height and width 100% will translate into the parent div height and width of 500px.

I have googled for the last 3 hours trying to figure out how to achieve this either by using plain css or css and javascript without any result.

Results that does not work:

- Porthole - requires access to the external websites.
- EasyXDM - requires access to the external websites.
- Accessing document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow does not work either - getting access denied error.

Any tips is appreciated!

Comment: check [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516763/delphi-embeddedwb-iframe-height-issue) , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly what you're describing before using EasyXDM and [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). As you note, access to the external website is required. You need some JavaScript code that runs on the external site's domain.

The browser won't allow JavaScript or CSS code on your site to access the DOM of the other site, so there's no way to know the height of the other site's page.